# Wann und unter welchen Umständen wurden lateinische Wörter im Deutschen nach Fall dekliniert?

Tags: grammatical-case, history, loanword, inflection, latin

In älteren Texten (zumindest in wissenschaftlichen) kam es vor, dass lateinische Wörter in deutschen Texten lateinisch dekliniert wurden, und zwar nicht nur gemäß Numerus (z. B. *Indizes* als Plural von *Index*), sondern auch gemäß Kasus. Ein Beispiel finde ich in Kants [*Kritik der Reinen Vernunft*](http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Kant,+Immanuel/Kritik+der+reinen+Vernunft/Einleitung/VI.+Allgemeine+Aufgabe+der+reinen+Vernunft), Fußnote 7:

> [...] [M]an darf nur die verschiedenen Sätze, die im Anfange der eigentlichen (empirischen) Physik vorkommen, nachsehen [...], so wird man bald überzeugt werden, daß sie eine **physicam puram** oder **rationalem** ausmachen[...].

Heutzutage würde man (wenn man schon einen lateinischen Ausdruck verwendet) "eine *physica pura* ausmachen" schreiben, und nicht den lateinischen Ausdruck nach Fall deklinieren. (*physicam puram* ist der Akkusativ von *physica pura*.)

Weiß jemand in welchem Zeitraum das üblich war, ob man das allgemein gemacht hat oder das nur die Marotte einzelner Autoren war, und seit wann man damit aufgehört hat? (Ebenso interessant ist, unter welchen Umständen das passiert. In dem Kantzitat wird ja einmal "Physik" verwendet und einmal "physicam".)

---

<sub>Dieses Phänomen war jedenfalls nicht auf das Deutsche beschränkt. In Árni Magnússons isländischen Prolegomena zur Sturlu saga, die wohl im frühen 18. Jahrhundert erschienen sein müssen, findet sich folgender Absatz:</sub>

> Grettis saga gengur nær **fabulæ** en **historiæ**; er full með **fabulas**, **parachronismos**; er interpoleruð úr einhverju **opere** Sturlu, og hans ætla eg vísurnar sé. […] Interpolatur mun hafa sett **fabulas** þar inn. […] Annars er eigi óvíst, að Grettis saga Sturlu hafi og **fabulosa** verið, og líkara þykir mér, að Sturla hafi komið við vísurnar […] Þessi saga er **fabulis plena**.

Hier werden lateinische Ausdrücke ziemlich schonungslos so behandelt, als ob sie isländische wären: Der Fall wird jedes mal richtig angepasst. (Besonders schön *úr [...] opere*, wo der Fall des lateinischen Wortes (Ablativ) gar nicht von der isländischen Präposition *úr* ("aus") verlangt wird (den gibt es auf Isländisch nämlich nicht),  aber der ist, den die lateinische Übersetzung *ex* verlangen würde.) Das scheint mir insofern relevant, als die ganze skandinavische Gelehrtensprache stark von der deutschen beeinflusst ist.

Comment: Eine Besonderheit ist "Jesus Christus", das im Genitiv oftmals lateinisch dekliniert wird, etwa in der feststehenden Phrase: "vor Christi Geburt" (Gen. Sgl.), oder auch "Die Jünger Jesu" (Gen. Sgl.)

Comment: @sgf: Nein, aber Juristen verwenden "Servitut" ja auch als eingedeutsches Fremdwort. Dort wo das aber nicht der Fall ist, wird das Latein bisweilen schon noch gebeugt. "Wenn der Käufer einen _animum rem sibi habendi_ (=Willen, die Sache für sich zu haben) nicht besitzt ..." halte ich für völlig korrekt, obwohl der Satz natürlich üblicherweise im Nominativ verwendet wird ("animus"). Ebenso lässt sich "Doktor" zB im Genetiv als "Doktoris" oder im Plural als "Doktores" verwenden, wobei das sicher nicht zwingend ist. Insgesamt kann man das wohl als, hm, "bilgungssprachlich" bezeichnen.

Comment: Ich werf noch den guten alten *Omnibus* in die Runde.

Comment: Bei Kant hat die Verwendung eines lateinischen Begriffs sehr oft die Funktion, einen terminus technicus einzuführen. Im beschriebenen Beispiel geht es ihm darum, deutlich zu machen, dass es sich um eine Physik _a priori_ handeln soll. Ich würde hier große Vorsicht walten lassen, von Kant auf die Zeit zu schließen. Er hat einen sehr spezifischen individuellen Stil (ich habe mal, nur halb im Scherz, den Begriff "Technobarock" dafür gehört), und es könnte gut sein, dass auch seine Deklination der lateinischen Begriffe nicht repräsentativ für den damaligen Sprachgebrauch ist.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Deshalb frage ich ja auch :)

Comment: @sgf Ja genau, ich wollte nur nochmal darauf hinweisen, dass ich es für relativ wahrscheinlich halte, dass es individueller Stil sein könnte, gerade weil es sich um Kant handelt. Aber klar, eine Antwort auf deine Frage ist das nicht. :-) Daher als Kommentar.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Gut möglich, dass Kant hier archaisch war, aber ich bin mir ziemlich sicher so etwas auch schon in (sehr) alten juristischen Texten (oder Amtstexten) gelesen zu haben. Irgendwann scheint das also durchaus üblich gewesen zu sein.

Comment: Ja, die Frage ist eine richtig gute und interessante Frage. Wenn man "Deklination Latein im Deutschen" googelt, kommt sie gleich als erster Hit :-) Ich bin gespannt auf die Antwort. Schade, dass man hier nicht +5 geben kann.

Comment: Vielleicht ist es bei Kant doch nicht auf termini technici beschränkt: Ich erinnere mich gerade, dass er in der _Grundlegung_ "der Heilige des Evangelii" schreibt (und sich damit auf Jesus bezieht). Da ist es kein terminus technicus.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Ja, in der Kirchensprache muss es ja ganz offensichtlich üblich gewesen sein. ("Der Leib Christi", "Mariä Heimsuchung", "Herz Jesu")

Comment: Man kann es vielleicht rausfinden, wenn man sich im google ngram-viewer ein paar eindeutig lateinisch flektierte Formen ansieht. _musicam_ und _physicam_ zeigen überhaupt kein klares Bild. _hostem_ schon eher. Aber es ist schwer, es gegen die deutsch deklinierte Form zu vergleichen, um die Konjunktur des Stammworts rauszurechnen. Oft sind es wohl auch einfach lateinische Textpassagen. Für mehr Recherche hab ich heute leider keine Zeit.

Answer (score 1):

Generell gilt, dass man die Grammatik der Herkunftssprache eines Lehnwortes nicht beherrschen muss, um ein solches Wort in einem deutschen Satz verwenden zu können.

Beispiele:

- Hobby (Englisch)

  > Welche **Hobbys** haben Sie?
- Pizza (Italienisch)

  > Ich habe heute zwei **Pizzas** gegessen.
- Kimono (Japanisch)

  > Der Gürtel deines **Kimonos** liegt im Bad.
- Steppe (Russisch)

  > Einsam und allein ritt er durch die **Steppe**.
- Safari (Swahili)

  > Walter ist erst gestern von einer **Safari** zurück gekommen.

In keinem der Fälle musste man eine der genannten Fremdsprachen lernen, um das jeweilige Wort in einem deutschen Satz verwenden zu können.

Das gilt prinzipiell und eigentlich auch für Latein und Altgriechisch.

Es hat sich aber vor allem in humanistisch gebildeten Kreisen eingebürgert, Begriffe, die aus diesen beiden Sprachen stammen, nach der Grammatik der Herkunftssprache zu beugen. Ich vermute, das geschah, weil man diese toten Sprachen damals als wertvoller ansah als die deutsche Sprache, oder weil diejenigen, welche diese Wörter in den deutschen Wortschatz einführten, schlichtweg nicht wussten, wie man sie in einem deutschen Satz richtig verwendet. Auch Angeberei halte ich vor allen bei jüngeren Texten für ein Motiv (siehe weiter unten).

Dieses Phänomen kann man derzeit auch mit der Sprache English erleben. Nicht selten wird man meinen ersten Beispielsatz so geschrieben lesen können:

> Welche **Hobbies** haben Sie?

Hier wurde englische Grammatik angewendet, um den Plural zu bilden (aus **y** wurde **ie**). Sogar das findet man manchmal, jedoch schon erheblich seltener:

> Ich habe heute zwei **Pizze** gegessen.

Hier wurde italienische Grammatik angewendet, um den Plural zu bilden.

Beide Sätze sind aber falsch. Hätte man nämlich konsequent die englische oder italienische Grammatik angewendet, hätten beide Substantive kleingeschrieben werden müssen:

> Welche **hobbies** haben Sie?
> Ich habe heute zwei **pizze** gegessen.

So weit geht dann aber zum Glück doch niemand mit der Ursprungsgrammatik.

Im Fall von Latein und Altgriechisch wurde die Beugung nach der Grammatik der Herkunftssprache aber jahrhundertelang praktiziert und auch an Schulen gelehrt. Viele dieser Sonderformen sind daher noch immer als Ausnahmen im deutschen Wortschatz vorhanden:

> der Leib **Christi** (statt *Christus*)
> zwei **Indizes** (statt *Indexe*)
> zwei **Status** (statt *Statusse*)

Von solchen alteingesessenen Ausnahmen abgesehen, ist es aber im Grunde genommen falsch, eine fremdsprachige Grammatik in einem deutschen Text anzuwenden. Wer das dennoch macht, tut dies heute oft aus Angeberei, um zu beweisen, dass er nicht nur das Wort an sich kennt, sondern dass er auch weiß, wie man es in der Ursprungssprache dekliniert.

Sehr oft findet man das in wissenschaftlichen Texten. Der Autor wollte sich in den meisten Fällen damit als besonders gebildet darstellen, wohl ohne zu wissen, dass er damit auch beweist, dass er die Regeln der deutschen Sprache nicht genügend kennt, oder sie zumindest ignoriert.

Die Erkenntnis, dass man in deutschen wissenschaftlichen Texten durchgehend deutsche Grammatik verwenden sollte, breitet sich nur langsam aus, und geht meiner Einschätzung nach mit der Einstellung einher, dass man wissenschaftliche Texte generell besser verständlich schreiben sollte, um sie auch einer größeren Leserschaft zugänglich zu machen.

Einen genauen Zeitpunkt dieser Umstellung kann man nur schwer nennen, weil dieser Wandel langsam und schleichend passiert. Ich würde aber sagen, dass das ein Wandel ist, der ungefähr in der Mitte des 20. Jahrhunderts begonnen hat, und noch immer andauert.

Comment: *Hobbies* und *Babies* sind meine Lieblingsbeispiele für falsch gebeugte Lehnwörter. Und besonders mag ich, dass die USA einen grade auch mit einem gültigen *Visa* nicht einreisen lassen (heute morgen im Radio)...

Comment: Die konsequente *Nicht*-Anwendung der italienischen Grammatik
führt allerdings auch zu irritierten Blicken – spätestens, wenn Du als Beilage eine Portion Spaghettos bestellst.

Comment: @Uwe, naja, das würde ich als Ausnahme sehen: Hier hat sich der italienische Plural einfach fälschlicherweise als Singular durchgesetzt. Man kann ja heutzutage durchaus Spagettis im Restaurant bestellen (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Spaghetti)

Comment: Mein Lieblingswort ist immer der Plural von "Status". Ich muss immer grinsen, wenn jemand mit "Stati" ankommt und meint, das sei richtig.

Comment: @Uwe: Dann versuch mal einen Zucchino zu kaufen :-)

Comment: @IQV: Fast alles ist besser als Statusse ...

Comment: @Uwe: Die Spaghetti sind als Mehrzahlwort ins Deutsche gekommen. "Ein Spaghetto" wäre ein Fall einer falschen Anwendung fremdsprachiger Grammatik. Genauso wie "ein Graffito" das jemand an eine Mauer gesprüht hat.

Comment: @IQV: Danke für »Status«! Ich habe dieses Beispiel auch hinzugenommen.

Comment: Wow, der letzte Absatz bezieht sich auf die Frage!

Comment: So weit gehen schon einige mit der Ursprungsgrammatik, Kleinschreibung von englischen Terminussen.

Comment: In Ahnlehnung an Kaktus nehme ich immer Stateen als Mehrzahl von Status

Comment: @ohno: Da werden dich aber nur wenige verstehen.

Comment: Die Antwort verfehlt leider das Thema der Frage. Lange beschäftigt sie sich mit einer verwandten Frage, um dann im letzten Absatz zu sagen, dass die Antwort auf die eigentliche Frage nicht bekannt ist. Daher gebe ich hier -1