# What is the correct form of "in the name of Jesus Christ"?

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive

When, for example, one might end a prayer in German saying "in the name of Jesus Christ". Which is the correct form?

The most frequent example I can find is in the genitive form:

> Im Namen Jesu Christi

However I also hear in the local congregation the following:

> Im Namen Jesus Christus
>
> In den Namen von Jesus Christus

My gut feeling as a non-native speaker says the first of the three is correct. But it is seldom used, either because it is truly incorrect or simply out of fashion.

EDIT: While other questions touched on the genitive form of Jesus Christ, none of them definitively answered my question, which was, what is the correct form for modern-day congregational usage. Thanks to those to answered here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper translation/name of Jesus Christ in German?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28500/what-is-the-proper-translation-name-of-jesus-christ-in-german). Also related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12053/declension-of-latin-nouns-or-phrases-in-german/

Comment: The questions are indeed related, but mine delved into the current accepted public/congregational usage, which was not answered specifically in either of those questions.

Comment: Meines Wissens beendet man Gebete im Deutschen überhaupt nicht mit "Im Namen X Ys". Das kann natürlich von Glaubensrichtung zu Glaubensrichtung variieren. Gebete enden, wenn formelhaft, mit Amen. Beim Anfang gibt es "Im Namen des Vaters, des Sohnes u. des hl. Geistes."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Answer

I think, in ecclesiastical contexts the first - "Im Namen Jesu Christi" - is the standard phrase. From a grammatical point of view "Im Namen von Jesus Christus" would be correct as well. But using this variant would show that you are not familiar with the church's tradition to use the latin Genitiv for the name of their Saviour, or it would suggest that you are not willing to submit yourself to the standard phrase, maybe indicating a distance to the church.

"In den Namen von Jesus Christus" is a wrong translation of "In the name of Jesus Christ", because it uses Akkusativ instead of Dativ - it would be translated to english with "*Into* the name of Jesus Christ"

"Im Namen Jesus Christus" is wrong, since - according to http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Jesus - "Jesus Christus" is not a valid Genitiv of "Jesus Christus"

## Additional Speculation

The latin declination of "Jesus Christus" seems exceptional in german grammar, normally the declination of foreign words follows german rules, with the exception of Nominativ Plural of some latin and a few greek words, which are sometimes declined after latin or greek schema (for instance: "Lexika" as plural of "Lexikon"). For this topic also see [Seit wann werden lateinische Wörter im Deutschen nicht mehr lateinisch flektiert?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34602/seit-wann-werden-lateinische-w%c3%b6rter-im-deutschen-nicht-mehr-lateinisch-flektiert)

The specialty of "Jesus Christ" in this question reminds me to the latin word *iovis* ("jupiter") who has had a whole own declination. That's why I guess that the latin Genitiv used for Jesus Christ in ecclesiastical contexts has the function to express the speciality of the name of their god. Even if this was not the intent of the exceptional declination, this is the effect - at least to me.

Comment: Der Genitiv von Eigennamen wird durch Anhängen von *"-s"* gebildet
(*"Annas"*, *"Franks"*). Eine Ausnahme ist, wenn der Name schon auf *"s"* endet,
dann wird nichts angehängt, was durch einen Apostroph kenntlich
gemacht werden kann, aber nicht muß (*"Thomas"* oder *"Thomas'"*).
Insofern ist *"Jesus Christus"* oder meinetwegen auch *"Jesus Christus'"* ein
regelmäßig gebildeter Genitiv, auch wenn das so nicht explizit im
Duden steht. ...

Comment: ... Die Regeln, ob ein Genitiv vor- oder nachgestellt
werden kann, sind aber etwas kompliziert, und eine der grundlegenden
Regeln ist, daß die Nachstellung nur dann möglich ist, wenn der
Genitiv als solcher erkennbar ist und nicht (in der Aussprache)
mit dem Nominativ übereinstimmt. Das ist der Grund, warum
*"Im Namen Jesus Christus'"* nicht geht – *"In Jesus Christus' Namen"*
mit *vorgestelltem* Genitiv wäre dagegen möglich, wenn auch unüblich.

Comment: Ich verstehe den Duden gerade so, dass der Genitiv von "Jesus Christus" unregelmäßig gebildet wird, und die regelmäßige Form daher falsch ist.

Comment: Der Duden gibt "Jesus'" als möglichen Genitiv von "Jesus" an
und "Christus'" als möglichen Genitiv von "Christus".
Dann ist "Jesus Christus'" als Genitiv zu "Jesus Christus" vielleicht
unüblich, aber bestimmt nicht falsch.

Comment: Oh ja, sorry, da hatte ich mich verguckt. Ich hatte die Tabelle nicht beachtet. Sorry für das Versehen!

Answer (score 0):

You name three variants, of which only one uses the correct latin case:

> Im Namen Jesu Christi

The following form is correct, but i don't like it because the genitive is ignored ("In den" should be "Im" or "In dem", but this is not the main issue here):

> Im Namen von Jesus Christus

The third variant seems not to be correct at all, I'd say.

> Im Namen Jesus Christus

Comment: Was ist mit *Im Namen Jesus Christus'* (wie *Im Namen Peter Müllers* oder *Im Namen Michael Klos'*?

Comment: @jkalden Siehe meinen Kommentar zur Antwort von jonathan.scholbach.